# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object only in my website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-artisan

Recently I updated my website and I found this error only in one view, on my localhost works fine, I uploaded it via FTP. I'm going crazy!

```
[2020-01-30 03:32:39] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/csinf298/resources/views/addEdit_promotion.blade.php) {"userId":3,"email":"email@email.com.mx","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/csinf298/resources/views/addEdit_promotion.blade.php) at /home/csinf298/storage/framework/views/a22f101b5a2d4fafaa9530cd13c1077aebc547ce.php:211, ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'id' of non-object at /home/csinf298/storage/framework/views/a22f101b5a2d4fafaa9530cd13c1077aebc547ce.php:211)
```

**My.blade**

```
$promotion->id
```

**I tried this too**

> $promotion->['id']

```
[2020-01-30 03:58:27] local.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' (View: /home/csinf298/resources/views/addEdit_promotion.blade.php) {"userId":3,"email":"carlos.cisneros@csinformatica.com.mx","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' (View: /home/csinf298/resources/views/addEdit_promotion.blade.php) at /home/csinf298/storage/framework/views/a22f101b5a2d4fafaa9530cd13c1077aebc547ce.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' at /home/csinf298/storage/framework/views/a22f101b5a2d4fafaa9530cd13c1077aebc547ce.php:176)
```

Comment: did u try  `$promotion->['id']` on localhost? I think in your server, there is no datas in promotions table.

Comment: your collection contains  ```"userId":3```, I think there is no id property to get. So try ```$promotion->userid```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **clear the caches** with `$promotion->id` as using the below command.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

If you still get the error then use `$promotion->userId` as I have seen in your error the object contains `userId`, not an `id`.

Comment: Ty! this was helpful, i need to do this before i upload a modification ever?

Answer (score 1):

Is your query returning array or object? If you dump it out, you might find that it's an array and all you need is an array access ([]) instead of an object access (->).
or 
Try This

```
$promotion->id
```

to

```
$promotion->['id']
```

or

```
$promotion[0]->poster['id']
$promotion->poster[0]['id']
```

It happen that after some time we need to run

```
 php artisan passport:install --force
```

again to generate a key this solved my problem ,

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

as you can see , it says `non-object` so you need to check 1st it's array or object if it is object then check id property is present or not 
and if it is array then 
rather then `$promotion->['id']`

use this

```php
$promotion['id']
```